# class="route-link" and class="fas fa-link" behavior confusion in node js web app

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I was building a simple web app in node js. I am new to using node js to build a web app but not new to web app development itself. I have plugged this web app to an api server that I have already built and deployed with a auth server plugged in between.

So, I have a login button. I also have a button that shows the logged in user profile. all good.

I added a new div for a new set of buttons.

```
    <div class="page" id="content-apiservicedemo">
      <div class="container">
      <hr>
      <p>here comes the simple api button</p>
      <button id="btn-call-api" disabled="true" onclick="callApi()">Call Api</button>

      <!-- Add a container to hold the response from the call -->
      <pre id="api-call-result"></pre> 
      </div>         
    </div>
```

and I used a link to show that section.

```
          <a href="/apiservicedemo">
            <i class="fas fa-link"></i> here
          </a>
```

and then, i found out, this link, constantly keeps reloading the entire page. I mean, to say, when i click on this, it triggers a one time page reload.

To add extra context, the way, the current nod js app is designed (I believe this is a standard thing in node js based single page application), it simply hides and shows a specific div depending on which route has been clicked.

and I used this the link this way. (this is the way the current link for home and profile details are written in this template/tutorial app)

```
<a href="/apiservicedemo" class="route-link">here 2</a>
```

and I am getting my new page, as I want, without reloading.

So, what is happening here? I am a little confused.

Comment: *and I used a link to show that section.* is the idea to click the link and it scroll into view? if so it would be `<a href="#content-apiservicedemo">`. If not please explain *constantly keeps reloading the entire page.* as links dont do that unless there is borky js on them

Comment: I have updated the question. it was poor wording on my choice. hope the updated question makes more sense.